# Deny all as default authentication-options in sshd

Tags: authentication, ssh, sshd

I want sshd (`OpenSSH_8.0p1`), to have no authentication methods (`AuthenticationMethods`) as standard, and therefor just drop the connection.
My plan is to create match-blocks like:

```
Match User user1
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

to allow people.

In my sshd_config, I have

```
PasswordAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
KerberosAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no

AuthenticationMethods none
```

but even so, the ssh client will prompt for a password if I try to login to the server using the wrong user.

I can see in the logs on the server

```
Sep  9 11:35:53 server1 sshd[113293]: debug1: userauth-request for user dummy service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Sep  9 11:35:53 server1 sshd[113293]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Sep  9 11:35:53 server1 sshd[113293]: debug1: authentication methods list 0: none
Sep  9 11:35:53 server1 sshd[113293]: debug1: authentication methods list 0: none [preauth]
Sep  9 11:35:53 server1 sshd[113293]: debug1: userauth-request for user dummy service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
Sep  9 11:35:53 server1 sshd[113293]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
```

and on the client

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
...
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickeydebug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
...
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue:
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Why is the server refusing password prompt, then changes its mind?

This is also happening with `UsePAM no`

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this in [unix.se] or [sf].

Comment: You have disabled "password" (old-school password auth) but don't have a new-school `KbdInteractiveAuthentication no` which may contribute. But I think since password is allowed for _some_ users it may be asked for all, if ignored. Don't want to give away if an account is valid or not based on how login responds